# custom placeholder for textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I need to create a custom placeholder for textfield. I created the custom placeholder method but not getting how to call it in my class the code is:

```
(void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Set colour and font size of placeholder text
[[UIColor redColor] setFill];
[[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.7] setFill];
[[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:5]];
}
```

in main .h 
created object for custom textfield class

```
CustomUITextFieldPlaceholder *txtName;
```

but not getting how to call for

```
**txt_userinput.placeholder=?**
```

and if have multiple textfield then how to call please help
thanks in advance

Comment: I am guessing why do you set the fill color twice ?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the method this way (in your CustomUITextFieldPlaceholder class) :

```
[self drawPlaceholderInRect:aRect];
```

Or if you want to call from outside the CustomUITextFieldPlaceholder class :

```
[txtName drawPlaceholderInRect:aRect];
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your `CustomUITextFieldPlaceholder` object and then you can call it -

```
CustomUITextFieldPlaceholder *obj = [[CustomUITextFieldPlaceholder alloc]init];
[obj drawPlaceholderInRect:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
```

Comment: getting <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0 after following the above procedure what it mean and how to solve this?